# How do I convert .JB2E files to a more common format?

Tags: conversion, file-format, jpeg

I'm trying to convert some `.jb2e` images, which I extracted from a PDF, into a proper, common image file format like PNG or JPG. I tried using `jbig2dec`, but that told me

```
jbig2dec FATAL ERROR Not a JBIG2 file header
```

What else can I try?

I'm using Devuan ASCII (~= Debian Stretch).

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue, and was able to get PNG versions by using `pdfimages` from the [Poppler utils](https://poppler.freedesktop.org/) on the original PDF, with the `-png` flag (and *not* the `-all` flag), so that it outputs all the images in the PDF as PNGs.

This is because the `-png` flag is not the same as the `-j` and `-jbig2` flags (all of these are selected by `-all`): `-png` sets the output format, which is the default for all images to be output as, converting if necessary. Converting is actually the default for `pdfimages`; with no format flags, it converts all images to PBM and PPM files. `-j` and `-jbig2`, on the other hand, specify *not to convert* images of those types, thus they are output in their original format. (Note that this means there's no option to convert images to JPEG in this program; only files stored as JPEGs are output as JPEG with the `-j` option.)

Comment: Wouldn't that only work if the PDF was created with PNG rather than JB2E images originally?

Comment: No, the `-png` and `-tiff` output options do conversions. The `-j`, `-jp2`, `-jbig2`, and `-ccitt` options request not to convert those file types and to output them as is. The `-all` option outputs some types verbatim, some as TIFF, the rest as PNG. (It was not clear to me either until I read it a lot of times.)

Comment: How inconsistent... :-( but thanks.

Comment: Somehow this silently fails for me. Poppler Utils 0.86.1 on Kubuntu Focal.

Comment: @jamadagni could you share more details of what you tried? Was this a file that output a `.jb2e` when you ran `pdfimages -all`?

Comment: @DanGetz Hmm thanks for prodding me on this. I tested more and I think the problem is rather that `pdfimages` expects an absolute path for the output, and `.` doesn't cut it. `-png` or `-all` only works when an absolute path is provided.

Comment: @DanGetz Actually the manpage says that I am to (somewhat unexpectedly) provide an “image root”: “writes one file for each image, image-root-nnn.xxx”. This is not an output path but a prefix for the output file paths. So `.` is interpreted as a prefix and I get `.-000.pbm` etc which are of course hidden from `ls` unless I add `-a`. Hence I was thinking it wasn't working. Providing `./` works for selecting current directory and you get `-000.pbm` etc in it.

Answer (score 3):

If the `.jb2e` is a single page extracted from a pdf, use:

```
jbig2dec -t png -o output.png /dev/null input.jb2e
```

According to `jbig2dec`'s manpage:

> `jbig2dec [options] global-stream page-stream`
>
> If a particular page references no global segment stream, `/dev/null` can be  passed  for  the  `global-stream`  argument  to request the embedded parser.

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly on my test file. Brings up a question for me: how is one to know that a file is a JBIG2 "segment stream" instead of a "single file"? (Just be aware that both types exist and try each way?)